# Oracle 11g and storing time with millisecond precision

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to create a database with statistics about moto GP and I want to store times from fastest laps and other. I need to store a time like minutes:seconds:milliseconds ... how can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `TIMESTAMP` type. It stores times with precision up to nano-second precision (default is micro-second).

See [Oracle Built-in Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i54330).

Pick a dummy year and date:

```
select to_timestamp('00/01/01 01:02:03.123456', 
                    'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;
```

Or you could use an `INTERVAL` type too:

```
SQL> create table foo (a interval day to second);       
Table created.
SQL> insert into foo values (to_dsinterval('0 01:02:03.123456'));
1 row created.
SQL> select * from foo;

A
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00 01:02:03.123456
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to store only time, not a date? I couln't find it how to insert a time value for ex. 3:52:09 (minutes:seconds:milliseconds)

Comment: Actually an interval is probably better. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Oracle does not store millisecond directly but it does store seconds
    with a fraction component which can help you to get the
    milliseconds.
 2. Not only millisecond rather you can get to microseconds too! In fact
    you can specify the number of digits that oracle stores in the   
    fractional part of seconds i.e. the precision part for `TIMESTAMP`  
    datatype. The default is platform dependant, on UNIX it defaults to
    6    and on windows it defaults to 3. The valid range is [0-9].
```

Refer : [DBA_BLOG](http://dbathoughts.blogspot.in/2008/05/storing-milliseconds-in-oracle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the timestamp data type (you can specify the accuracy if you want). 
If you want to store values from different time zones, use timestamp with timezone instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use timestamp at all for storing the data. If the information of minutes, seconds and milliseconds are available before the storage, I'd rather create a separate table with three number fields in it to hold the information; of cause, with a surrogate key as well :-)